# Joining 4 tables with Mysql and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 4 tables, that's all in a relationship, yes they love each other :p

- Products
- Product Categories
- Product Category Relationships
- Product Images

I want to join these 4 tables in one query, here is my Codeigniter code to do this;

```
function list_products($limit = 10, $offset = 0, $category)
{
    $this->db->select('p.url, p.name, p.title, i.image');
    $this->db->from('products p');
    $this->db->join('product_categories c','c.id = r.category_id',
                    'left');
    $this->db->join('product_category_relations r',
                    'r.category_id = c.id','left');
    $this->db->join('product_images i',
                    'p.id = i.product_id AND i.default = 1','left');
    $this->db->where('c.url',$this->category_url.$category);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

When i execute this function / query, the result is an error about defining "r".

> Unknown column 'cms_r.category_id' in 'on clause'

The query:

> SELECT `p`.`url`, `p`.`name`, `p`.`title`, `i`.`image` FROM
>   (`cms_products` p) LEFT JOIN `cms_product_categories` c ON `c`.`id` =
>   `cms_r`.`category_id` LEFT JOIN `cms_product_category_relations` r ON
>   `r`.`category_id` = `c`.`id` LEFT JOIN `cms_product_images` i ON
>   `p`.`id` = `i`.`product_id` AND i.default = 1 WHERE `c`.`url` =
>   'kategori/yilbasi' LIMIT 12

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You assign `r` to be similar to `product_category_relations` after you use it.

Here you write:

```
$this->db->join('product_categories c','c.id = r.category_id','left');
```

But what is `r`? You answer this question only in the next statement.

```
$this->db->join('product_category_relations r','r.category_id = c.id','left');
```

---

Provide sample SQL Create script, if you want concrete answer.

Comment: R is product_category_relations. as you can see, i didnt use "AS".

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan But you say that `R` is `product_category_relations` **after** you use that `R`.

Comment: I know what it should be, i'm asking how it will be... So, how can we do that any opinion? :)

Comment: Then, please, provide your `SQL Create Script` for these four tables. Hardly anyone will spend time to create database with four tables on their own just to answer one question.

Comment: Are you kidding me :) I'm asking for a theoretical information that everyone who understands my problem can easily guess what happening.

Answer (score 0):

@Edward Ruchevits your query does not join because of r.category_id define after joining of product_category_relations r, you need Relationships between **products** and **product_categories** then your query something be like

```
$this->db->join('product_categories c','c.product_id = p.id','left');
```